# what does mean in java <=0?0:1;

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand this program in java but i'm new to this language.

Can you tell me what

```
<=0?0:1;
```

means?

It's from the following code that decrements the elements of a matrix (tabu)

```
 public void decrementTabu(){
        for(int i = 0; i<tabuList.length; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j<tabuList.length; j++){
            tabuList[i][j]-=tabuList[i][j]<=0?0:1;
         } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a short form for a if/then query: (tabuList[i][j]<=0) ? 0 : 1. THis means if the value in tabuList[i][j] is less than 0 then subtract 0, else subtract 1. The question mark somehow replaces if and the colon replaces the else.

Comment: basically asking for homework help that a quick look through any tutorial or language book would have shown.

Comment: This is old, but this will only work for a square array. The second for loop should be "for(int j=0; j<tabuList[i].length; j++)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tabuList[i][j]-=tabuList[i][j]<=0?0:1;
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
tabuListEntry -=tabuListEntry <=0?0:1;
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
tabuListEntry = tabuListEntry - (tabuListEntry <=0?0:1);
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
int decrementAmount = tabuListEntry <=0?0:1;
tabuListEntry = tabuListEntry - decrementAmount ;
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
int decrementAmount = 0; 
if(tabuListEntry  <= 0) {
    decrementAmount = 0;
} else {
    decrementAmount = 1;
}
tabuListEntry = tabuListEntry - decrementAmount ;
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
int decrementAmount = 0; 
if(tabuListEntry  > 0) {
    decrementAmount = 1;
}
tabuListEntry = tabuListEntry - decrementAmount ;
```

can be written as:

```
int tabuListEntry = tabuList[i][j];
if(tabuListEntry  > 0) {
    tabuListEntry = tabuListEntry - 1;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the assignment back to `tabuList[i][j]` in most of your examples.

Comment: @Oded Yes I am, thanks for pointing it out. "The re-asignement of the modified value back in to the array will be left as an exercise for the user" - take that, every high-school math book ever written! :)

Answer (score 15):

You are not looking at the operator correctly.

This is the [conditional operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is the only ternary operator in JavaScript or Java (and other languages, such as C#). Ternary means it has three parameters.

Essentially this is what it means:

```
(condition)?(true branch):(false branch)
  param1        param2        param3
```

In your code example, the condition (param1) is:

```
tabuList[i][j]<=0
```

If true, 0 (param2) is returned. If false, 1 (param3) is returned.

The return value is then decremented from `tabuList[i][j]` via the `-=` operator.

The whole statement:

```
tabuList[i][j]-=tabuList[i][j]<=0?0:1;
```

Can be written as:

```
if (tabuList[i][j] > 0)
   tabuList[i][j]--;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is work as if condition, will take "c<=0?0:1;"

This means if c is less than or equal to zero then answer is 0 else 1